# Windows 10 usb 3.1 port stops working when device is plugged in another

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers, usb-3

I am using windows 10 pro, I have my wifi running using a wifi Dongle. The dongle is constantly plugged in an USB port.

Whenever i plugin any other device to a port which is directly above it the wifi stops working.

**Note** here that I do not get any message or sound indicating that usb has been disconnected. It just stops working.

As soon as I disconnect the device on the other port the wifi comes back on and starts working automatically.

**Another thing to note** is that the port stops working when a device is plugged in the port on top of it and not with any other port.

I have the ASUS z170 Pro gaming board and have installed the latest drivers for USB and Chipset.

The port that does not work is `USB 3.1 Gen 2 port(s) (Type-A)`

Also, I have uncheck the `allow the computer to turn off this deivce` as mentioned here https://www.pcworld.com/article/3045567/windows/how-to-keep-charging-your-usb-devices-past-your-pcs-bedtime.html

Comment: Is the wifi dongle usb 3.0? Try pluging it into a usb 2.0 legacy port if you have one.

Comment: its a USB 3.1 Gen 2 port(s) (Type-A)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure that one USB bus is interfering with the other.  Assuming that the actual USB ports are not wired in parallel, (which would obviously cause this), I suspect that the power draw of your new USB device is responsible for turning off, disabling, "un-powering", or somehow shutting down your WiFi dongle's USB.

**Let's determine if it is the USB bus, or a USB power issue, first:**

- When the WiFi stops working, is there a power indicator on the WiFi itself to see if it is still getting 5V?
- Have you gone to the USB properties to see how much power is being drawn by each device when plugged in, both before and after the new device is plugged in?
- One solution of course, would be to reroute one of the other USB ports to the front panel so it won't interfere.

I had a USB conflict issue recently that I solved -- (See my DaaBoss answer: [Seagate HDD periodically disables/enables](https://superuser.com/questions/1311947/seagate-hdd-periodically-disables-enables/), in the: **"This worked.....!", paragraph**).  In my solved problem, one device caused the USB drive to disconnect and then reconnect every five minutes.

Comment: In addition to power issues, SuperSpeed USB and wireless are somewhat notorious for interfering with each other because harmonics of 2.4 GHz wireless fall into the frequency range used by SuperSpeed, etc.

Comment: How do I "reroute" back USB port to the front? The usb port in question here are soldered to the MOBO